# Apache mod rewrite not working in Mac Sierra

Tags: macos, mod-rewrite, apache2

Apache version is 2.4,rewrite mod is active in httpd.conf
AllowOverRide is set to all and require all granted in vhost config
I am just getting a 404 not found error.
Am I missing any setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that all the document roots have `AllowOveride All`. It should listen to the closest node in the folder hierarchy but in my experience wasn't the case. 
The primary `<Directory />` section in `http.conf` was defaulted as `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing, but in my case I had multiple PHP version, and was editting the wrong httpd.conf file.

The configuration of OSX native PHP is in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Hope this helps.